# How do I use put Method on Cache in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working in Laravel v4.2 and want to put an array into the cache. When I try to get data from the cache it returns false all the time and the cache has no data. Below is my working code...

```
$posts = array(
    [0] => 2365,
    [1] => 2366,
    [2] => 2367,
    [3] => 2368,
    [4] => 2369,
);

$time = 60;

Cache::put('views-87', $posts, $time);

$data = self::getPostsFromCache('views-87');

public function getPostsFromCache($key)
{
    if (Cache::has($key)) {
        return Cache::get($key);
    }
    return array();
}
```

Result

> empty Array()

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Depending on your cache driver, do you see results in the cache? (file, database, memcached?)

Comment: @JackPoint I am using memecahched

Comment: Then see if there is something stored there.

Comment: @JackPoint in which file?

Comment: Thats not stored in a file, you need a tool or script to display everything from memcached